# Run Script After Another Script in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work with [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). I have an html like this:

**index.html**

`<h1>Example</h1><div class="instagram-widget"></div>`

**index.js**

```
 jQuery('h1').mouseenter(function () {
jQuery(this).addClass('fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('fadeOutUp').removeClass('fadeInUp').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass('fadeOutUp');
    });
}); });
```

Everything is works!

---

I have an Instagram with API (I can show my photos - dont worry with API). I add an API code to **index.js**. I dont put all code here to make simplicity for the question. I append

`jQuery('<a>').attr('href', url).append( // inside it, append an image
    jQuery('<img>').attr('src',src),
    jQuery('<div class="comment">').html(comment)  ) // end append
    .appendTo('.instagram-widget')`

then I change `jQuery('h1').mouseenter(function () {` to `jQuery('.comment').mouseenter(function () {`

Doenst work. It lookslike because `.comment` executed at the same time with `jQuery('.comment').mouseenter(function () {` because at one file.

**QUESTION**

How to make `.comment` works? Is there any function that load a script after another script finish completely?

Comment: how about changing the `.comment` to avoid conflict?

Comment: @claudios can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for that - good way, or just `.setTimeout()` - bad way.

With Promise you can be sure that one piece of code will be executed only after another.